# SQL : Update table_1.column_b if table_1.column_a = table_2.column_a

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables like these. I want to update table_1.column_b **if** table_1.column_a **=** table_2.column_a

table_1

```
column_a   | column_b
----------------------------
   X1       |    0    
   X2       |    0    
   X3       |    0    
   X4       |    0    
   X5       |    0
```

table_2

```
column_a
--------
   X1
   X2
   X3
```

the result should be:

table_1

```
column_a   | column_b
----------------------------
   X1       |    1    
   X2       |    1    
   X3       |    1    
   X4       |    0    
   X5       |    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table_1
set column_b = 
(
select count(*) 
from table_2 s
where table_1.column_a = s.column_a
)
/* oracle can bug out when a subquery returns nothing, i.e. Null */
where exists 
(
select 1 
from table_2 s
where table_1.column_a = s.column_a
)
;
```

Extra info about the select 1 in where exists.  It is just something I tend to add, just in case.  It is defensive programming.

Not entirely sure it is needed, **in this particular case**,  because I assume the count(*) subquery will return 0 for your X4 and X5 entries in table a above.

Suppose you were doing this instead...  (The 1 in the select isn't really below isn't important, it could be any number or a numeric column from table_2 if you had one).  The important thing is that we are not doing a count(*) this time so X4 and X5 will not get anything from table_2.

```
update table_1
set column_b = 
(select 1
     from table_2 s
     where table_1.column_a = s.column_a
)
```

In this case, X4 and X5 will not get a subquery result and Oracle will try to assign null to table_1.column_b for those rows.  **If that column is set to NOT NULL, you will get an error.**

By adding the where exists at the end of the query you are telling Oracle not to try updating table_1 where there is no matching table_2 row.  So this update null issue never happens.

The basic idea for the boilerplate is to first qualify your update subquery as you need to update the column.  Then repeat the conditions as a where exists at the end of the query to avoid Oracle trying an update where the subquery doesn't return anything.

Note that I could have left count(*) in the where exists subquery.  Except that I am only looking for the existence of a matching row and I am not actually interested in a count(*) there so I optimize a bit by asking Oracle to select a 'cheaper' result set.

If you had multiple column updates with different subquery criteria, then that won't work.  You'd have to split the update up into different queries.  Or use Oracle NVL (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) to catch the NULLs and replace them.

Comment: U rock! It's work. The thing is I don't know about "select 1" you mentioned above. Can you tell me more about it?

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution:

```
update table_1 a
set    a.column_b = 1
where a.column_a in (select * from table_2);
```